# Django App on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I've been struggling with the issue where I believe my account has been shutdown due to having too large of a table? Correct me if I'm wrong.

```
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OL (DATABASE_URL)
Plan:        Dev
Status:      available
Connections: 0
PG Version:  9.1.8
Created:     2013-01-06 18:23 UTC
Data Size:   11.8 MB
Tables:      15
Rows:        24814/10000 (Write access revoked)
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
```

I tried running

```
heroku pg:psql HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OL
```

to look at the tables, but how do I determine which table has too many rows and is flooding my database inside psql?

Once, I do determine which table this is. Can I just go to `heroku run manage.py shell` and call `Model_with_too_many_rows.delete.all()` and my account will no longer be shutdown? Are there other steps that must be taken to have the smaller db register with heroku so that my write access will be returned?

Sorry, if these questions are trivial, but my understanding of SQL is limited.

EDIT: I also believe that there was a time where my database was flooded with entries, but I have since deleted them. Is there any command I can run to resize the databse to acknowledge  that the number of rows have been reduced? Or does heroku do this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a smarter way to check row count by table, but I use the [pg-extras](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras) plugin and run `pg:index_usage`.

You will regain write access to your database within ~5 minutes of getting back down below the 10k row limit – Heroku will check this and update the limit automatically.

Comment: Thank you that plugin worked magically. However, I noticed that " django_admin_log" was taking up 20k rows. I'm guessing that this is the admin logs. Assuming, that I don't need to keep track of admin actions would it be safe just to delete these entries? Do admin logs never get deleted automatically? Do I need to manually delete them each time?

Comment: Those questions are specific to the framework you're using - one I'm now familiar with :(